# How to draw a line with animation by React Native

Tags: react-native

I have some graphs and need to show the drawing path.
In the iOS, i can stroke the graph in CALayer with CABasicAnimation 
How to do animation for stroking in React Native

Comment: this might be handy https://github.com/react-native-china/react-native-ART-doc/blob/master/doc.md

Comment: Can you give example or gif what exactly you want?

Answer (score 1):

To render an animated Line in a chart, you can use a charts library. One of the simplest and best-documented charts libraries in react native is - [react-native-gifted-charts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-gifted-charts)

It will not only make the animations easy to implement, but also let you easily customise and beautify your chart. [Here](https://gifted-charts.web.app/static/media/lining.a0796470.mov) is an animated Line chart made using this library. And below is the code for the same-

```js
import { LineChart } from "react-native-gifted-charts"
    const App = () => {
    const lineData = [
        {value: 0, dataPointText: '0'},
        {value: 20, dataPointText: '20'},
        {value: 18, dataPointText: '18'},
        {value: 40, dataPointText: '40'},
        {value: 36, dataPointText: '36'},
        {value: 60, dataPointText: '60'},
        {value: 54, dataPointText: '54'},
        {value: 85, dataPointText: '85'}
    ];
    return (
        <View style={{backgroundColor: '#1A3461'}}>
            <LineChart
                initialSpacing={0}
                data={lineData}
                spacing={30}
                textColor1="yellow"
                textShiftY={-8}
                textShiftX={-10}
                textFontSize={13}
                thickness={5}
                hideRules
                hideYAxisText
                yAxisColor="#0BA5A4"
                showVerticalLines
                verticalLinesColor="rgba(14,164,164,0.5)"
                xAxisColor="#0BA5A4"
                color="#0BA5A4"
            />
        </View>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

it is an old question but I post the answer for the reference. You can use Animated from "react-native". you have to consider three directions: Horizontal, Vertical and diagonal. I added the comments to clarify the code

```js
    import React, { ReactElement, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
    import { StyleSheet, Animated } from "react-native";

    // size prop is to determine the size of graph
    export default function Line({ size }): ReactElement {
        // Pythagorean theorem to calculate the diagonal height
        const diagonalHeight = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(size, 2) + Math.pow(size, 2));
        // if we dont use ref, animation will be reinitialized everytime we rerender the component
        //  we want animation to be rendered when component reredners so we use useeffect
        const animationRef = useRef<Animated.Value>(new Animated.Value(0));
        useEffect(() => {
            // timing is a linear animation
            Animated.timing(animationRef.current, {
                toValue: 1,
                duration: 700,
                // true might not work with the all properties that you need to animate. true might improve animation performance
                useNativeDriver: false
            }).start();
        }, []);
    
        return (
            <>
                {conditionForVerticalDisplay && (
                    // if we are using Animated, it has to be inside Animated.View not View
                    <Animated.View
                        style={[
                          // you can pass multiple style objects
                            {
                                // interpolate maps the animated value to another value
                                height: animationRef.current.interpolate({
                                    inputRange: [0, 1],
                                    outputRange: ["0%", "100%"]
                                })
                            }
                        ]}
                    ></Animated.View>
                )}
                {conditionForHorizontalDisplay && (
                    <Animated.View
                        style={[
                           
                            {
                                height: animationRef.current.interpolate({
                                    inputRange: [0, 1],
                                    outputRange: ["0%", "100%"]
                                })
                            }
                        ]}
                    ></Animated.View>
                )}
                { conditionForDiagonalDisplay && (
                    <Animated.View
                        style={[
                           
                            {
                                height: diagonalHeight,
                                transform: [
                                    {
                                        // negative will shift it upward. 
                                        // translateY: -(diagonalHeight - size) / 2
    
                                        translateY: animationRef.current.interpolate({
                                            inputRange: [0, 1],
                                            outputRange: [size / 2, -(diagonalHeight - size) / 2]
                                        })
                                    },
                                    {
                                        rotateZ: conditionToPosOrNegDiagonal === "MAIN" ? "-45deg" : "45deg"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]}
                    ></Animated.View>
                )}
            </>
        );
    }
```